# How to manage radio-buttons with checked value in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this function where I want to output radio-buttons. If isDefault is true, the radio-button should be checked by default. But it doesn't work as it should because when I click a radio-button that is not checked by default it won't get selected or it switches back to the isDefault-button. I guess this due to re-render and during re-rendering the default radio-button get's reselected. Is there a way to prevent that behavior? Thanks in advance.

```
    const renderUpgrades=(item)=>{
        return item.optionModules.map((optionModule,index)=> {
            console.log(optionModule.module)
            if (optionModule.module && optionModule.module.selectionRequired) {
                return(
                    <div>
                        <h4>{optionModule.module.name}</h4>
                        {optionModule.module.options.map((moduleOptions) => {
                                if(optionModule){
                                    return (
                                        <div>
                                            {
                                                moduleOptions.isDefault?
                                                    <div><input type="radio" value={moduleOptions.option.name} name="selectionRequired" checked="checked"/>   {moduleOptions.option.name}</div>:
                                                    <div><input type="radio" value={moduleOptions.option.name} name="selectionRequired"/>   {moduleOptions.option.name}</div>
                                            }
                                        </div>
                                    )
                                }else{
                                    return console.log("No shifts applied");
                                }
                            })
                        }
                    </div>
                )
            }
})
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

React will accept a boolean for checked so you can remove the ternary and just do something like this:

```
<div><input type="radio" value={moduleOptions.option.name} name="selectionRequired" checked={moduleOptions.isDefault}/>   {moduleOptions.option.name}</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but the result is still the same. The default radio-button is selected but when I press another radio-button and then again another radio-button the default button is going to be selected.